# pg_restore --clean removes access to schema public

Tags: postgresql

Code:

```
#   1. Cleanup, in case we run this script more than once
psql -U postgres -c 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS t1'
rm -rf t1_dump

#   2. Create database and grant all to janbet
psql                -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE t1'
psql        -d t1   -U postgres -c 'GRANT ALL ON DATABASE t1 TO janbet'

#   3. Check access to schema public (it works)
psql        -d t1   -U janbet   -c 'CREATE TABLE public.x AS SELECT 1'

#   4. Create pg_dump
pg_dump     -d t1   -U janbet   --format=d --file=t1_dump

#   5. Restore database t1
pg_restore  -d t1   -U postgres --clean t1_dump

#   6. Check access to schema public
psql        -d t1   -U janbet   -c 'CREATE TABLE public.y AS SELECT 1'
```

Output:

```
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE
GRANT
SELECT 1
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
```

In psql, \dn+ returns this before restore:

```
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema  
        |          | =UC/postgres         |
```

and this after restore:

```
                        List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   | Access privileges |      Description
--------+----------+-------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres |                   | standard public schema
```

So, clearly some privileges are missing. Questions:

1. Why does pg_restore change priviliges?
2. If this is a bug, are there any other similar issues?
3. Is there any approved workaround? I know that `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO janbet` works well, but maybe this is not necessary?

While googling I found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20170823140058.2ojn2ajcamd43s76%40holly), but there are no clear answers to my questions there.

Version:

```
                                                           version
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.4 (Ubuntu 10.4-0ubuntu0.18.04) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0, 64-bit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/11976.1503584315%40sss.pgh.pa.us) response to the bug report you link to agrees that this is a bug, and I share this opinion.

I believe that just nobody got around to fix it...

Maybe you can poke the hackers list.

Comment: Good answer. Seems like an important bug, and yet a lot of time has passed without a fix.  If the pg_dump command is executed with -c to clean database objects, the resulting dump file includes "GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;"  So, the developer could run that command manually.